# Динамическое обновление выводимой информации MySQL

Tags: mysql, ajax

Как написать запрос к базе с выбором через ajax для вывода информации из таблиц привязанных к projects

```html
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <?php
    $dbconfig = m ysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM category order by category_name asc" ; 
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>">
      <?php echo $row[ 'category_name'];?>
      </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
<select name="system" id="system" class="form-control"></select>
<select name="projects" id="projects" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, создаём кнопку, вешаем на неё обработчик на клик -> дальше идёт запрос на `ajaxtest.php` и возвращает нужные `option's`

```js
$('#superbutton').click(function() {
  $.get(
    "/ajaxtest.php", {
      category: $('#category option:selected').attr('value')
    },
    onAjaxSuccess
  );

  function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    $('#projects').append(data);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="superbutton">Поехали</button>
```

**ajaxtest.php** *(подправьте как вам нужно)*

```
<?
$dbconfig = m ysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$id = (int)$_GET['category'];
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE `category`='$id'" ; 
$result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
  <option value="<?=$row['project_id'];?>">
  <?=$row[ 'project_name'];?>
  </option>
<?php }?>
```